# Google map display not properly

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am going to display location of company at google map according to user's address.
By the way, The input address is different, but only the same address is displayed every time.
Help me
my code is follow.Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var address = "<?php echo $address;?>";
var latitude = 0;var longitude = 0;
    //alert(address);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    //var address = document.getElementById(address).value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
        } else {
            alert("Request failed.");
        }
    });
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
    zoom:5,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCY-        jGtLHPdttTiekXaSPncp6haCA3VeLU&callback=myMap"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a question? You say it doesn't display properly, so, something displays, but what? Do you have errors in the developer tools console? have you done any basic debugging at all to see what part of the code runs and what doesn't for example?

Comment: Note: `geocode` is *asynchronous* ... so, `latitude,longitude` will still be `0` when you call `new gogole.maps.Map`

Comment: as an aside, you can use `results[0].geometry.location` for the `center` property, rather than fiddling around like you do

Answer (score 0):

Because `geocoder.geocode` is *asynchronous* you won't have updated `latitude` and `longitude` before you use them, therefore your map center is 0,0

Initialise the map in the callback to `geocoder.geocode` as follows

```
function myMap() {
    var address = "<?php echo $address;?>";
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var mapProp = {
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                zoom: 5,
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        } else {
            console.error("Request failed.", status);
        }
    });
}
```

> Note: in the code above I use `center: results[0].geometry.location,` to set the map centre, to avoid deconstructing the lat/long from a `LatLng` object, only to create a new `LatLng` object from the retrieved co-ordinates - seems a wasted effort :p